# Area code is not set when creating category

Tags: magento2, category

I'm using this function to create categories

```
public function fetchOrCreateProductCategory($categoryName, $parentId = 1)
{
    //when parent id is 1, then it's root category
    $parentCategory = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($parentId);

    $category = $this->categoryFactory->create();
    $cate = $category->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('name', $categoryName)
        ->getFirstItem();

    if (!$cate->getId()) {
        var_dump('in');
        $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath())
            ->setParentId($parentId)
            ->setName($categoryName)
            ->setIsActive(true);
        var_dump('in 2');
        $category->save();
    }
    var_dump('end');
    return $category;
}
```

Then I call it

```
$rootCategory = $this->fetchOrCreateProductCategory('Default Pro Category');
```

It works

Then I call it with a sub category

```
$subCat1 = $this->fetchOrCreateProductCategory('Cofee',$rootCategoryId);
```

And here it fails right after

> in 2

with the message

> Area code is not set

Obviously something is wrong when I try to save a subcategory...but I can't figure it what is it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this class please:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace here;
use Magento\Framework\App\State;

class SetAreaCode
{
    /**
     * @var State
     */
    private $state;

    /**
     * @param State $state
     */
    public function __construct(
        State $state
    ) {
        $this->state = $state;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $areaCode
     * @return void
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function execute(string $areaCode): void
    {
        try {
            $this->state->getAreaCode();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->state->setAreaCode($areaCode);
        }
    }
}
```

this is your class:

```
public function fetchOrCreateProductCategory($categoryName, $parentId = 1)
{
    $this->setAreaCode->execute('adminhtml');

    //when parent id is 1, then it's root category
    $parentCategory = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($parentId);

    $category = $this->categoryFactory->create();
    $cate = $category->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('name', $categoryName)
        ->getFirstItem();

    if (!$cate->getId()) {
        var_dump('in');
        $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath())
            ->setParentId($parentId)
            ->setName($categoryName)
            ->setIsActive(true);
        var_dump('in 2');
        $category->save();
    }
    var_dump('end');
    return $category;
}
```

Cheers